# How to use helm with token based authentication system on EKS

Tags: kubernetes, client-side, kubectl, amazon-eks, kubernetes-helm

We use `helm` to manage our `kubernetes applications`.
We use kubectl commands like this :
`kubectl --token $TOKEN get pods`

So we use token based authentication system to run `kubectl` as opposed to auth info stored at `~/.kube/config` file.

Now problem is : We are not able to run any of helm commands as all helm commands throw : `Error: Unauthorized`.

So question is how to use helm with token based authentication system.

Context :
Recently our DevOps team moved from `self managed K8S` to amazon's EKS. Only mechanism they provided to authenticate kubectl is through token.

Comment: did you solve this as of now? one year later:)

Answer (score 2):

Currently Helm does not support Token based authorization mechanism with Kubernetes API. Therefore, there is no option for user-provided bearer token verification.You can find Github [issue](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/1918) with a proposal of Authentication and Authorization support in Tiller.

Helm 3 Design [Proposal](https://github.com/helm/community/blob/master/helm-v3/000-helm-v3.md)  has been announced with a significant changes to be implemented such as the new Security [concepts](https://github.com/helm/community/blob/master/helm-v3/007-security.md) .